# read and open dicom images using python

Tags: python-3.x

how to read and display dicom images using python. I am new to python and IT field.  please some one briefly tell me about the packages and libraries needed for dicom image processing and codes for opening dicom images.

Comment: What do you want to achieve finally? Just opening the files might not be the end of your journey...

Comment: i want to segment the tumor in the dicom images.

Answer (score 24):

DICOM images are generally used to store medical images. They are highly informative. Along with image data it stores lots of key patient information, such as, patient’s name, age, sex, doctor’s name etc.

If you just want to **preview dicom images** without extracting any information then use the following code. You need to install pydicom python package, you can install using `pip install pydicom` -

```
import pydicom as dicom
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

# specify your image path
image_path = 'data/train_images/sample.dcm'
ds = dicom.dcmread(image_path)

plt.imshow(ds.pixel_array)
```

If you want to **convert the image** to png/jpg then you can do the following -

```
import pydicom as dicom
import cv2   

# specify your image path
image_path = 'data/train_images/sample.dcm'
ds = dicom.dcmread(image_path)

pixel_array_numpy = ds.pixel_array

image_format = '.jpg' # or '.png'
image_path = image_path.replace('.dcm', image_format)

cv2.imwrite(image_path, pixel_array_numpy)
```

source: https://medium.com/@vivek8981/dicom-to-jpg-and-extract-all-patients-information-using-python-5e6dd1f1a07d

Comment: I have tried this approach.. there is an image loss in jpg

Comment: Oh really? This always did the job for me, let us know which approach you used

Comment: Note that the values in pixel_array_numpy might need to be scaled to the range 0-255 by  doing pixel_array_numpy  = 255 * pixel_array_numpy / pixel_array_numpy.max()

Comment: I have tried with both .png and jpg, image loss.  `dcmread` function works for me.

Answer (score 7):

If you are working on Windows, I suggest you install Anaconda for working with Python. It has most of the libraries and packages.

I suggest you start with installing the following libraries:

1. pydicom (for python version > 3.0)
   Link: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pydicom
2. Matplotlib (if not working in Anaconda)
3. Numpy (if not working in Anaconda)

The following code should display your images:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os, glob
import pydicom
import pylab as pl
import sys
import matplotlib.path as mplPath

class IndexTracker(object):
    def __init__(self, ax, X):
        self.ax = ax
        ax.set_title('Scroll to Navigate through the DICOM Image Slices')

        self.X = X
        rows, cols, self.slices = X.shape
        self.ind = self.slices//2

        self.im = ax.imshow(self.X[:, :, self.ind])
        self.update()

    def onscroll(self, event):
        print("%s %s" % (event.button, event.step))
        if event.button == 'up':
            self.ind = (self.ind + 1) % self.slices
        else:
            self.ind = (self.ind - 1) % self.slices
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.im.set_data(self.X[:, :, self.ind])
        ax.set_ylabel('Slice Number: %s' % self.ind)
        self.im.axes.figure.canvas.draw()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

os.system("tree C:/Users/Dicom_ROI")

plots = []

for f in glob.glob("C:/Users/Dicom_ROI/AXIAL_2/*.dcm"):
    pass
    filename = f.split("/")[-1]
    ds = pydicom.dcmread(filename)
    pix = ds.pixel_array
    pix = pix*1+(-1024)
    plots.append(pix)

y = np.dstack(plots)

tracker = IndexTracker(ax, y)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('scroll_event', tracker.onscroll)
plt.show()
```